Influential mathematics books in Schrodinger's time which helped him solve the equation named after him?
Do Erwin Schrödinger biographies discuss which mathematical books specifically helped him to solve his famous equation in the 1920s? For example in a recent article, Schrödinger’s original quantum–mechanical solution for hydrogen Eur. J. Phys. 42 (2021) 035405 (21pp) https://doi.org/10.1088/1361-6404/abb9ff, the authors made interesting observations about the "lost art" and mention Schlesinger's book. The book is in German,Schlesinger L 1900 Einführung in die Theorie der Differentialgleichungen: Mit Einer
Unabhangigen Variablen (Leipzig: G J Göschensche Verlagshandlung). I am curious about other books that might be relevant besides this one in his time.

In his first paper, ‘quantization as an eigenvalue problem (part I)’
[1], Schrödinger presents a naive argument to‘derive’ the
Schrödingerwave equation and then proceeds to solve for the
nonrelativistic energy eigenstates of hydrogen, determining the
bound-state energy eigenvalues (for E < 0) and the corresponding
unnormalized wavefunctions.He also briefly discusses the continuum
solutions with E > 0. Themethod he uses is called the Laplace method
for solving differential equations. This technique, though similar to
the much more familiar Laplace transform, is somewhat different. It is
employed to solve differential equations of arbitrary order, but with
coefficients that are at most linear functions of the dependent
variable. Schrödinger relied heavily on the first edition of the
differential equation book by Schlesinger [2], which uses this
methodology in its treatment of differential equations. Schrödinger is
somewhat light on the specific details for howthe solution is carried
out and, since it is not described in nearly all quantum textbooks,
this strategy he used to solve for the first wavefunction has become
somewhat of a lost art.


First relevant publication: E. Schrödinger, "Quantisierung als Eigenwertproblem." Annalen der Physik, Series 4, Vol. 79, No. 4, 1926, pp. 361-376. In a footnote on p. 363 Schrödinger thanks Hermann Weyl for showing him how to deal with a particular differential equation (7), and also references L. Schlesinger's 1900 textbook on differential equations, in particular chapters 3 and 5.

2nd relevant publication: E. Schrödinger, "Quantisierung als Eigenwertproblem." Annalen der Physik, Series 4, Vol. 79, No. 6, 1926, pp. 486-527. Footnote on p. 496 references a publication by Sommerfeld & Runge, Ann. d. Phys., 35, S. 290, 1911 that shows (relying on a remark by P. Debye) how to derive one kind of equation from a different kind of equation. In a footnote on p. 518 the author thanks E. Fues for characterizing a particular differential equation.
